# Project template with three projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template

Is it possible to create a project template containing three projects?

I've built a sample project for my client which contains the basic structure for all their new applications. It would be sweet to be able to create a project template from it to make everything a lot easier.

Projects in the solution

- ProjectName.Abstractions
- ProjectName.Services
- ProjectName.WebClient

What I really would like is a solution template =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no solution templates, but there are multi-project templates:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a solution which contains three project as above. Just follow method of creating multi-project template.

And then in .csproj file of main project,
replace

```
<ProjectReference Include="\ProjectName.Services\ProjectName.Services.csproj">
      <Project>{7D31A904-BA57-4CDA-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX}</Project>
      <Name>ProjectName.Services</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

with below code,

```
<ProjectReference Include="\$safeprojectname$.Services\$safeprojectname$.Services.csproj">
      <Project>{7D31A904-BA57-4CDA-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX}</Project>
      <Name>$safeprojectname$.Services</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```